# How to calculate size of HTML text to be drawn

Tags: html, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

How can I create pages and display them in UIWebView from a HTML file?
How can I calculate and draw the amount of text from HTML file.

Comment: Those sound like two separate questions. Please move the first one into a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSURLRequest and load it into the view. The view takes care of displaying the html automatically. Note that you can get URL can be local, on a website, on a server as php, anything. I don't understand the second question. Please reframe it. Thanks.

```
// Request the contents of the abtWebView
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.whatever.com/aDirectory/stuff.html"]];

// Load the webview
[self.theWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: thank you very much Arni. My second question is related to this thread which is not been answered properly.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707210/uiwebview-paging-line-cut-off